# Does JSF manage access authorization for @ManagedBean methods?

Tags: security, jsf, primefaces

I have a @ManagedBean @SessionScoped class to represent a user session. Assume it has a theoretical method `doHorribleThings()`. Access to methods of this bean through JSF can, for example, be enabled through Expression Language attributes such as `action="#{userSession.doHorribleThings()}"` on a Prime Faces `p:commandButton`.

My question is, does JSF manage access security for such method? Can a user issue performing the action of a button that is not being rendered for him, e.g. by sending an artificial HTTP package? Or does JSF capsulate a virtual client desktop that stretches accross the network, effectively enabling access control through GUI design?

Answer (score 0):

No, JSF doesn't have an access security for invoking a method in a managedbean other than the UI, as far as I know.

Because if your able to mimic an action that happens through the click of a JSP/Primefaces button with a manual HTTP request then JSF container cannot identify the difference between the two and hence work the same way for both the request

Comment: Second part of this answer is fundamentally wrong. You forgot that, on contrary to HTTP, JSF is stateful.

Comment: Sorry BalusC but I can't agree with you, the questions is to find out whether there is a security mechanism in JSF to differentiate between click through an UI and a manual HTTP request right?
I think I'm still right here. Yes I know JSF is stateful, what if I add a valid JSessionID in my manually constructed HTTP request. Now JSF has no other way than to process the request!

Comment: OP didn't ask for that. The crucial part is: *"Can a user issue performing the action of a button that is not being rendered for him"*.